# Apache2.2 Incorrectly Resolving URLs

Tags: apache-2.2, php, http

I've recently moved some PHP files from an Apache2.2 server on Windows 7 to an Apache2.4 server on Ubuntu. However, I'm now getting errors resolving URLs. When I click a link to something like `https://www.example.com/index.php?page=home`, I get a 404 because I'm redirected to `https://www.example.com/page=home`. However, when I type in the URL manually, it works. Does anyone know of a solution to this problem?

**UPDATE**: Actually, I was mistaken, the new server is an Apache2.2 server.

**UPDATE**: Here's the Directory tag from the VirtualHost config file.

```
<Directory /var/www/site1>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Post some configs please. You should always do that in case something of a configuration appears to be wrong.

Comment: Check that you have "execcgi" option set and that you're loading the php module.

Comment: It already displays PHP pages, including retrieving data from a MySQL database. However, the URLs are the issue.

Comment: If it works because you are retyping the link exactly as it is in the `<a>` tag, then either something in index.php is redirecting you based on referrer or something in your config is redirecting you based on referrer.

Comment: Strangely, when I manually type in the URL while on the page linking to the error, it fails. Could it be a referrer issue?

Comment: DerfK, as far as I know, my Apache config has not been modified, except for a few minor details.

Comment: I actually discovered that the new server is running Apache2.2 and not Apache2.4.

Comment: Configs, and _actual_ examples. "Something like" isn't going to cut it here, I suspect.

Comment: What PHP config options should I look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was entirely in my own PHP code. I was having the page redirect with a location header, but I used the wrong $_SERVER variable. I've corrected this and the page is now working like it should.

Thanks to everyone who helped along the way. You guys helped me narrow down the problem to the eventual solution.

Answer (score 0):

You’re not providing a lot of details here, but it sounds like maybe some Apache `mod_rewrite` configs in your `.htaccess` file on the root are acting oddly.

Another issue that might be in play is the root URL setup on your website is misconfigured.  So it’s not properly forming URLs.

But you are not explaining what kind of PHP site this is. Is it a CMS? Is it something common if not?  Or is it homebrewed PHP?

Comment: There are no .htaccess files in the directory and mod_rewrite is disabled. It's a custom-made PHP system. I'll post the directory tag from the VirtualHost config file.

Comment: Ok, it's posted in the question above.

Comment: Sorry, but that’s not enough to help. Too in the dark. But I can assure you that the version of Apache2 is not at fault.  I’ve migrated tons of Apache sites & it’s an extremely backwards compatible piece of software.  My guess is there are configuration paths or settings in your custom PHP coding that is causing the issue. But again, it’s almost impossible to say without really looking at your local setup.

Comment: I've written a small test page for arguments and it encounters no issues. I'll look into my application as the source of the problem.